# Not able to get the wifi ssid in Android

Tags: android, wifi

I am trying to get the name of connected wifi in Android. I tried the following code. But the ssid I am always getting `<unknown ssid>`.

```
public void registerNetworkCallback() {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback
                (new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                        Log.i("WifiActivityTest", "onAvailable ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLost(Network network) {
                        Log.i("WifiActivityTest", "onLost ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCapabilitiesChanged(@NonNull Network network, @NonNull NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities) {
                        Log.i("WifiActivityTest", "onCapabilitiesChanged ");
                        WifiInfo wifiInfo = null;
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                            wifiInfo = (WifiInfo) networkCapabilities.getTransportInfo();
                            Log.i("WifiActivityTest", "wifiInfo.getSSID() " + wifiInfo.getSSID());
                            Log.i("WifiActivityTest", "wifiInfo.getBSSID() " + wifiInfo.getBSSID());
                            Log.i("WifiActivityTest", "wifiInfo.getNetworkId() " + wifiInfo.getNetworkId());
                        }
                        super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities);
                    }
                });
    }
```

But when I try with the following code I am getting all the ssid and all capabilities.

```
public List<String> getWifiScanResults() {
        List<String> capabilities = new ArrayList<>();
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (hasAccessPermission()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return capabilities;
            }
            List<ScanResult> networkList = wifi.getScanResults();
            if (networkList != null) {
                for (ScanResult network : networkList)
                {
                    capabilities.add(network.capabilities);
                    Log.w ("WifiActivityTest", network.SSID + " capabilities : " + capabilities);
                }
            }
        }
        return capabilities;
    }
```

I added the following permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Please help me to get the current connected wifi ssid and other details. I am using Android 12 and 13 devices to check.

Comment: You need to pass the flag https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO in your NetworkCallback() constructor.